# How does File Explorer open files?

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd

It's maybe stupid question, but what happens behind the scenes when i double click the word app, or .exe app?

For 'Non-Developer' it just opens the file in right environment after doubleclicking. But I would like to know, how is it done, how can the file manager know what to open? (.docx in word, .txt in texteditor,etc...)

+ I would like to know how can I do that in Node.js, is it the best way to use child_process and if statements for every suffixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a file association to tell Windows how to treat a certain file extension. You can type `assoc` in a Windows Command Prompt to see them. As an example:

```
C:\test>assoc .txt
.txt=txtfile
```

So Windows knows now, that the file with the extension `.txt` is a `txtfile`.

`ftype` defines, how that filetype is to be handled:

```
C:\test>ftype txtfile
txtfile=%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1
```

So whenever you doubleclick on a file, Windows checks if it is associated with any filetype. Then it looks up, how to handle that filetype and executes that command (in the example above, it opens Notepad with the filename as a parameter).

Both `assoc` and `ftype` are able to change the settings (for example to open `.txt` files with another editor). But if you try that, do yourself a favor and note the original settings, so you are able to revert your changes when needed.

The changes can also be done directly in the registry (not recommended, when you are not experienced in handling the registry)

Answer (score 0):

For Node.js, you can use child_process to shell out to [the `start` command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) which does similar things as the File Explorer.

E.g. `start some/path/to/file.docx` will open that file in the default program associated with the format.

Comment: As `start` in this answer is the built-in Windows `cmd.exe` command in this case, you should, _(unless in the context of something which would alternatively need to escape backward slashes)_, use Windows file path separators too, `start some\path\to\file.docx`, and preferably use doublequotes as best practice, `cmd.exe /D /C "Start "" "C:\Users\AKX\Desktop\file.docx""`.

Comment: @Compo [`child_process.exec` uses a shell by default.](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

Comment: Your path in your answer does not use child_process, that is why I mentioned it. You've use only a string which is not tied to the command you mentioned. Also unless child_process specifically runs `cmd.exe` with the `/D` option, it may not work as intended, because the end user may have AutoRun commands which may affect everything done in that shell. `%ComSpec%` is just `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` on an unmodified system, and when run without options, uses `/C` only by default.

Comment: ..of course just to expand upon that, I suppose that there's no reason to assume that the end user has not configured the `ComSpec` variable to be something other than `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`, too. Which means that `start` may not exist as a command in their alternative shell, or may exist, but work differently.